# Looking for a verb that means division into multiple branches

Tags: word-choice, academia

I am looking for a verb that describes division into multiple branches. The context is an academic report that describes a graph that contains four curves over the range of -3 to 3. Over half the range all curves are identical, but starting from 0, each curves follow a different trend.
I know that bifurcation describes a similar situation with two curves.

Comment: branch out is the most usual.

Comment: Bifurcation is used in the context of a single expression that is single valued over part of the range and becomes multivalued at some point. But it is only one curve, not two. If you have four expressions that happen to evaluate similarly over part of their range, the curves don't divide or branch, they overlap then diverge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the simple intransitive multi-word verb **fan out.**

- *The graphs fanned out beyond x = 1·6*

> **fan out** (from some place)
>
> to spread outward from a particular area.
>
> - *The paths seem to fan out from the wide trail that starts at the house.*

[[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fan+out)]

**Diverge** is perhaps a little more formal, but does not really generate the same image.

A few have felt the need to introduce 'polyfurcate', but thankfully dictionaries have ignored this.

Comment: I think "polyfurcate" has a nice ring to it :)

Answer (score 1):

One option would be the word [fork](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fork)

> a division into branches or the place where something divides into branches

This can also be used as a verb, so you could say

> Over half the range all curves are identical, but starting from 0, each curve *forks*.

Comment: 'Fork' doesn't entail multiple branches; in fact when used as a verb, it usually applies to a bifurcation.